# Oil in combustion chamber

Tags: oil, generator

I received a power generator with oil in the combustion chamber. Apparently the gen was tipped over, so I suspect oil travelled through the valve? and into the chamber and carburetor. Can I still run it this way? Should I use a additive cleaner? Or should I just take it apart and clean it?

Thanks for your input.
Nelson

Answer (score 2):

i would remove the spark plug, spray in some wd40 or equivalent (something to break down the oil) and then spin it over so that any excess gets forced out.

Once most has come out, then you can put the spark plug back in and start it - check the oil level..
It will smoke at the beginning but it will sort itself out as long as everything is ok.

Comment: I'd also suggest checking the spark plug to ensure it hasn't fouled in the process.

Answer (score 0):

To sharpen my lawn mower blade ,I tip the mower on it's side and oil gets into the combustion chamber . I pull the plug and clean off the oil. When I start it ,it smokes for a minute but has apparently not done any damage.